# SQL: count customer that never bought a product, in a group by

Tags: mysql

I have just this MySQL table:
`Order(customer_id, wine_id, price)`

An example

```
wine_id |   customer_id |   price
1       |   1           |   13€
1       |   2           |   13€
1       |   3           |   13€
2       |   1           |   17€
2       |   3           |   16€
3       |   4           |   15€
3       |   2           |   15€
```

and want to get number of customer who never bought a product, per product.

So there are 3 wines and 4 customers. All the customers in this table bought at least a bottle of wine.
In the example above, I expect the following:

```
wine_id |   count(distinct customer)
1       |   1
2       |   2
3       |   2
```

In fact the wine with id *1* has been bought by *3* customer out of *4* total customers ... so since I want the customer who never bought the product the expected result is *1*.

I thought about this:

```
SELECT 
    o1.wine_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o1.customer_id) 
FROM
    order o1
WHERE
    customer_id NOT IN (SELECT 
            o2.customer_id
        FROM
            order o2
        WHERE
            o2.wine_id = o1.wine_id)
GROUP BY o1.wine_id;
```

The idea is to get into the subquery the customers that bought a wine, and then put this in the where clause passing the grouped wine. But clearly there is something wrong in this assumption. It returns 0 row. Why can't I access a value in the sub-query?

Can you guys help me with this query?

Comment: Give a sample data and expected result.

Comment: From this table, you can just get number of customer who ever bought per product. If you want get who never bought, you should tell us where you store you customer. Or all of customers are in this table?

Comment: @Forward, thank you for your reply. All the customers are in this table. I'll add this information in the question

Comment: then where is your expected result? the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    wine_id,
    cus_num - count(distinct customer_id) never_bought_num
from yourtable
join (select count(distinct customer_id) as cus_num from yourtable) t
group by wine_id
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e338a/1) in sqlfiddle.

In your case, you should count all the customers in table `order`, this is total number, then minus number of customer who bought product, you will get never bought number.

***Edit***:
Two ways can solve your sql error.
1) Set your `sql_mode` without `only_full_group_by`;
2) Replace `group by wine_id` to `group by wine_id, cus_num`.

Why this issue???

Check official doc [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: thank you! Works fine in sqlfiddle, as expected. But on my MySQL it gives me the error:
`Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't.cus_num' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`